# Monotouch: getting NSDictionary value

Tags: c#, ios, mono, xamarin.ios, push-notification

I have the remote notification dictionary, but how do I get the AlertBody out?

```
NSDictionary remoteNotification = options 
     [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as NSDictionary;
```

from remoteNotification ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

Sending Push Notifications:

```
oPushService.QueueNotification(NotificationFactory.Apple()
    .ForDeviceToken("YourDeviceTokenASDASD!@#SDF")
    .WithCustomItem("MyCustomItem","Item 3")
    .WithAlert("Alert pop message")
    .WithSound("default")
    .WithBadge(7)));
```

On the Client Side:

```
void processNotification(NSDictionary options, bool fromFinishedLaunching) {                   
(options != null && options.ContainsKey(new NSString("aps"))) {    
    NSDictionary alertMsg = options; 
    NSObject codeCustomValue = alertMsg[NSObject.FromObject("MyCustomItem")];
    // .... and continue your code....  }
```

Hope it helps!

Armando

Answer (score 2):

```
        var k = new Object[] {"key"};
        var v = new Object[] {"value"};
        NSDictionary a = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(v,k);
        NSObject value = a[NSObject.FromObject("key")];
```

U can try for this it worked for me ....

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you sent to the application. Basically, it's a JSON request you sent converted into a NSDictionary form.